# Redirecting with cookies in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to drop a cookie for a specific view, so that a user can only visit that page once.  However, what I have now is not redirecting the user away from the view on repeated viewings like I want.  Here is what I have:

```
public function getWelcome() {
            // Drop cookies and check for it...

            $cookie =  Cookie::get('cs_welcome');

            if(isset($cookie) && $cookie == 1) {
                return Redirect::to('/fans/'.Auth::user()->url_tag);
            }
            else {
                $cookie = Cookie::forever('cs_welcome', 1);
            }

            return View::make('fans.welcome');
```

Basically I want them to only see the fans.welcome view once.  If it is a repeated visit, I want them to go to /fans/Auth::user()->url_tag.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO I believe that with that approach a user can wipe their navigation cookies and then when they go into their account they we'll se the welcome page again.

To have a real persistence that the user saw the welcome screen I recommend that you save that information in your database and relate that to the user.

Let's say `$user->sawWelcomePage = true`

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
1. Register the user
2. Login the user automatically after creating the account
3. After login redirect to welcome page
```

Also, if you don't want to log in a user automatically you may skip it.

In both cases, keep a flag, any field in `users` table, for example: `verified` and by default keep it `NULL` once the use logs in then update the field with `1` or any truthy value so you may check if that field is `NULL` then the user 
should be in the `welcome` page otherwise don't let the user go to that page.